# What does it mean for a data set to have Gaussian-distributed noise?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I need to find an answer for this question.

What does it mean for a data set to have Gaussian-distributed noise?

Can anyone help?

Comment: another way to look at it is that the data set values that you have are corrupted (on either side of the gaussian mean) with a random variable that follows a Gaussian distribution.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's normal assumption, because Gaussian distribution is easy to treat.

And also assume there are many small independent noise source in your data, then by Central Limit Theorem, your noise will be Gaussian.